Mode selection for Boost converter
I am currently working on a problem for designing a boost converter. Below are the parameters that are used for the calculations.
Vin = 180V, Vout = 360V
L = 25 μH, Operating current is 15A and the switching frequency is 50kHz. By referring the documentation provided in ti.com I was able to calculate the Inductor ripple current which was equal to 72A.
My question is what type of conduction mode does the converter operate? CCM or DCM?
PS: I am new to this topic, so please forgive me if I have made any mistakes in the calculation or in explaining the question :)

Try to calculate how big the inductor, ripple and losses are at BCM. Which one hurts the most and you would like to have smaller. That will tell you the direction you want to go in.

What precisely do you mean by operating current?


By referring the documentation provided in ti.com I was able to
calculate the Inductor ripple current which was equal to 72A

That's not too far off: -

My ideal boost calculator indicates that the ripple current is 65.7 amps and operating in DCM.

My question is what type of conduction mode does the converter
operate? CCM or DCM?

If I interpret "operating current" as load current then it's working in DCM.
You can find the boost calculator on my basic website.
